# How to assign thousands of rows of species to a functional group in R studio?

Tags: r

I would like to assign each one of my species in my data-set to a functional group.
I have tried the following code which only gives me a value for one of my species...

```
Spp = dplyr::select(DOG, Sub.Plot., Species, CV)

Spp$Func <- ifelse(grepl("Andropogon ternarius", Spp$Species), "Grass", "")
Spp$Func <- ifelse(grepl("Conyza canadensis", Spp$Species), "Forb", "")

     Sub.Plot.                       Species CV   Func
1      185-188           Triplasis americana  3     
2      185-188    Eupatorium compositifolium  8     
3      185-188              Croton michauxii  5     
4      185-188             Conyza canadensis  2   Forb
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Andropogon ternarius is not in your `Species` variable, that's why 'grass' is not being returned.

Comment: Grass isn't being returned because the second line for Forb is overwriting it. The first line says If "Andropogon ternarius" then "Grass" else Blank. The second line then supersedes that by saying If "Conyza canadensis" then "Forb" else Blank. I would build a table with first column Species and second column Func. Have that contain all of your unique mappings. Then you cause use `left_join()` from `dplyr` to join `by = "Species"` and have it bring in the `Func` column.

Comment: As an alternative to @Adam's suggestion to use `left_join`, you could use `dplyr::case_when` to replace the multiple `ifelse` calls (which are overwriting each other)

Comment: Thanks everyone! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to bring suggestions from the comments into an answer.

The left join solution

```
library(dplyr)

refTbl <- data.frame(
  Species = c("Andropogon ternarius", "Conyza canadensis"),
  Func = c("Grass", "Forb")
)

Spp <- select(DOG, Sub.Plot., Species, CV) %>% 
  left_join(refTbl)
```

And the case solution

```
library(dplyr)

Spp <- select(DOG, Sub.Plot., Species, CV) %>% 
  mutate(Func = case_when(
    grepl("Andropogon ternarius", Species) ~ "Grass",
    grepl("Conyza canadensis", Species) ~ "Forb",
    TRUE ~ ""
  ))
```

or step-wise without the pipes

```
library(dplyr)

Spp <- select(DOG, Sub.Plot., Species, CV)

Sapp$Func <- case_when(
  grepl("Andropogon ternarius", refTbl$Species) ~ "Grass",
  grepl("Conyza canadensis", refTbl$Species) ~ "Forb,
  TRUE ~ ""
)
```